# Why would this 'sapply' function in R return an invalid response given my function?

Tags: r

```
CountNew <- function(x){
     if (x==0) y <- 1
     return(y)
 }
allCF$NewECount >- sapply(allCF$Count, CountNew)
```

Using the above code, if a value in EquipCount in allCF is currently equal to 0, I want to change it to 1 while keeping the other values the same, then maintain the values of the rest of the values not equal to 0. I made sure these were numbers (not factors) through the str(rawCF) command

But then I get the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found

What is causing this problem?

Comment: You could vectorize it instead of looping i.e. `allCF$Count[allCF$Count==0] <- 1`

Comment: You get that error because `y` isn't defined in your function unless `x == 0`.  @akrun's solution seems like what you want though

Answer (score 0):

The code logic is wrong.

What if the element does not satisfy `x==0`? The function will return a y which is not defined. Add one line will solve it:

## Solution 1

```r
allCF <- data.frame(Count=c(0,0,-1))

CountNew <- function(x){
  y=x
  if (x==0) y = 1
  return(y);
  } 


allCF$NewECount  <- sapply(allCF$Count, CountNew)
```

## Solution 2: Vectorize your CountNew function

```r
allCF <- data.frame(Count=c(0,0,-1))

CountNew <- Vectorize(function(x){
  if (x==0) return(1);
  return(x);
  } 
)

allCF$NewECount  <- sapply(allCF$Count, CountNew)
```

Now you may do `CountNew(allCF$Count)` directly.